# About localization of integral closure at maximal ideals.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, integral-extensions

I've been struggling in this problem:

> If $m$ is a maximal ideal of $R:=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x^2(x+1))$, when is $R_m$ integrally closed (normal)?

Well, I know that $t=y/x$ is integral over R, but isn't in R, what makes it not normal. Moreover, $R[t]\simeq \mathbb{C}[x]$ is the integral closure of R in $Frac(R)$ and for $\overline{m}=\overline{(x-a,y-b)}$ such that $(y^2-x^2(x+1))\subseteq m$ (maximals of R) and $S=R-m$, we have $S^{-1}\mathbb{C}[x]$ as the integral closure of $R_m$ in $S^{-1}Frac(R)$. So the question is:

> Is it true that $S^{-1}Frac(R)\simeq Frac(R_m)$?

If yes, then I can advance by noticing that when $a\neq 0\Leftrightarrow x\not \in m \Leftrightarrow x \in S$, then $t=y/x\in R_m$ and $R_m=R_m[t]\simeq S^{-1}R[t]\simeq S^{-1}\mathbb{C}[x]$, that is, $R_m$ is normal. But:

> Is it true that $R_m[t]\simeq S^{-1}R[t]$?

I also know that for $a=0, b\neq0$, $y\in S$ and $t$ is invertible in $R_m$.

> Then what happens with $R_m[t]$? Perhaps $R_m[t]\simeq S^{-1}\mathbb{C}[x]\simeq \mathbb{C}$?

If the answer to this question implies on $R_m$ is normal, we're ok. Now, when $a=b=0$, we have $x,y\not \in S$, then $r=(y/s)/(x/s)\in Frac(R_m)$ is integral over $R_m$, because $r^2-\frac{(x+1)}{1}=0$ and $r\not \in R_m$. Thus $R_m$ isn't normal.

> Can you point out what I missed and my mistakes?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I asked another question around this problem, but focusing on singularities, which is not the point here.

Comment: It seems to me that you missed my comment and the answer to your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027581/normality-of-localizations-in-polynomial-rings).

Comment: Just for giving you the opportunity to miss another comment: $S^{-1}(R[X])\simeq(S^{-1}R)[X]$ for *any* multiplicative set $S\subseteq R$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really missed your last comment about the 1-dimensional noetherian ring, which is indeed the answer... I took a while to understand why though. Thanks for the hint on this question, for some reason knowing that something is true turns the proof "easier".